# Log the user that modified a row in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have the following code which writes the last edit date and time in the last cell of the row:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // Note: actRng = return the last cell of the row modified
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  // Note: date = return date + time
  // Note: user = return the user email
  var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-0300", "dd-MM-yy HH:mm");

  //var user = event.user;  // Note: event.user will not give you collaborator's Id
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser();

  // Note: setcomment = Inset a comment with the user email
  // Note: setValue = Insert in the cell the date + time when this row was modified
  lastCell.setValue("'" + date).setComment(user);
}
```

This also comments the modifier email on the last cell. However, this is only commenting the owner's email ID and not the email ID of the person with whom the shared is shared and who has made the change.

How can I log the email id of the person who last edited a row?

Comment: Google has rules about when you can know the identity of the user, especially for simple triggers (i.e. the functions using reserved names, such as yours). If you have created an installed trigger for this function, know that it is activating twice. Please share your research on this task.

Comment: geteffective user is blank when the sheet is edited by a shared user, but the email ID is commented when the sheet is edited by the owner. Trigger is not activating twice.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Reviewed the restrictions that apply to simple triggers? Reviewed available Apps Script methods? Considered using a different GSuite API?